# Dhtml Menu problems with navigate it

Tags: html, css, dhtml

I found a vertical menu but I'm having some problems with it, i can't navigate properly in the submenu because i miss the menu when i move down.

Here I leave the website www.timetarget.com/newsite

please any help or comments will be help me .

Cheers

Comment: Work.on.your.accept.rate! Go to your profile and accept answers that helped you. People will like you more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu links are far too wide, such that the mouseover target area overlaps the submenus. Instead of `142px`, it should be something like `110px`. Also, you could try setting the `z-index` property for the submenu `<li>` elements higher so that they display above the original menu, but that won't solve your problem by itself.

By the way, instead of styling each element individually, you can give any group of similar elements the same `class` attribute, and style that class with whatever properties all those elements share.